# In Perl, how do I pipe the output of one command to the input of another?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how can pipe the output of one command to the input of another?

I want to do it the way the shell does it, but without using the shell.

I know that I can do this using the shell and escaping the arguments to the command, but I don't want to use the shell.  I would also prefer using modules that are distributed with Perl, as opposed to ones on CPAN.

I could use `fork` and `exec` manually, but that doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want and what code you have already?

Comment: Please do show us something you've tried or explored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy using [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run).

```
run \@cmd1, '|', \@cmd2;
```

For example,

`prog0`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );
print("The parent's PID is $$\n");
run([ 'prog1' ], '|', [ 'prog2' ]);
```

`prog1`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print("cmd1's parent's PID is ".getppid()."\n");
```

`prog2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   print("Got <<$_>>\n");
}
print("cmd2's parent's PID is ".getppid()."\n");
```

Output from `prog0`:

```
The parent's PID is 6619
Got <<cmd1's parent's PID is 6619>>
cmd2's parent's PID is 6619
```

Comment: That uses a 3rd party library; I want to be able to do it using just the standard library.

Comment: Are you asking me to copy IPC::Run here?

Comment: I am basically looking for the primitive operation here.  Specifically, I am looking for the Perl primitive that calls `fork()` + `exec()` (Unix) or `CreateProcess()` (Windows).  Given that, I can implement the rest myself using pipes; the question is what that primitive is.  Do I do it using `fork()` even on Windows, or does Perl have a better way?

Comment: `fork` is available as `fork`. `exec` is available as `exec`, and `CreateProcess` is available from Win32::Process. You'll also need `select` or threads. `select` doesn't work on pipes in Windows, so you'd need to use sockets instead.

Comment: is Win32::Process always available on WIndows?

Comment: I think it is of you use ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl. Maybe not if you build your own.

Answer (score 0):

Using [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

```
perl -e 'exec(bash => (-o => "pipefail", -c => "find . -type f|xargs ls -l"));'
```

or

```
perl -e 'exec("bash", "-o",  "pipefail", "-c", " find . -type f|xargs ls -l");
```

Comment: That uses the shell, which I don't want.